# How to write custom query codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have following query and its working in MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM usr_booking 
WHERE shop_id ='1' 
AND services_dates='2019-01-02' 
AND (start_time BETWEEN '10:00' AND '11:00' OR end_time BETWEEN '10:00' AND '11:00');
```

But if I convert in Codeigniter way then query not working, How can I write this query in Codeigniter?
I tried with the following code but showing "Database Error"

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM usr_booking 
WHERE shop_id ='1' 
AND services_dates='2019-01-02'
AND (start_time BETWEEN '10:00' AND '11:00' OR end_time BETWEEN '10:00' AND '11:00')");
```

Where I am wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @NageshKatke: i am getting "Database error"

Comment: Did you load your database?

Answer (score 2):

you can refer to this [page](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) regarding on CI query builder.

Base on your question you are trying to convert MySQL query into CI query builder right? Let's give it a try, based on your code you are selecting a data with a condition, so it looks like this:

```
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("usr_booking ");
        $this->db->where("shop_id",1);
        $this->db->where("services_dates",'2019-01-02');
        $this->db->where("start_time" >= '10:00');
        $this->db->where("start_time" <= '11:00');
        $this->db->or_where("end_time" >= '10:00');
        $this->db->where("end_time" <= '11:00');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
```

Basically, this will return data on object type. Use `result_array()` if you want to convert it to array.

If you are getting an Error `Database Error` check your **database.php** file under **application/config** you must set up your *default database config*. You can refer [here.](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html)

**NOTE:** `Don't forget to load your database as always or set it on` **autoload.php**

Let me see if there's an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

In your model, create a function

```
function customData($str)
{
   $query = $this->db->query($str); 
   return $query->result_array();
}
```

In your controller load the same model and call above method

```
$querySTR = "SELECT * FROM usr_booking 
WHERE shop_id ='1' 
AND services_dates='2019-01-02' 
AND (start_time BETWEEN '10:00' AND '11:00' OR end_time BETWEEN '10:00' AND '11:00')";

$result = $this->model_name->customData($querySTR);
if($result){
 //Write your code
} else {
  echo 'Error Code: '.$this->db->_error_number().' -- Error Message: '.$this->db->_error_message();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to write your own custom query in Codeigniter, You can try this.
Create a function inside your model with like this

```
function customQuery()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM usr_booking WHERE shop_id ='1' AND services_dates='2019-01-02' AND (start_time BETWEEN '10:00' AND '11:00' OR end_time BETWEEN '10:00' AND '11:00')"); 
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Load this Model inside controller and now call this function from your controller like this!

```
$this->customModel->customQuery();
```

this will return result array.
Thank you